# How do you store data with BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

If I add an input field to the profile page or checkout page for "favorite color" how would I store that value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know *(November 2016)*, there is only one native feature that supports this, and you can view more information on this via [this Official BigCommerce Support Article](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Editing-Form-Fields).

The alternative method would be to manually send the custom input data to an externally hosted program that either saves it in your own database, or attaches it to a BigCommerce resource via the BigCommerce API (such as saving the input value for an order in the `Order Notes` section).